# What is Admission + Wax Hand means in Madame Tussaud's Museum in Washington DC?

Tags: museums, washington-dc

I hope https://www.madametussauds.com/washington-dc/en/tickets/ is the official site to buy Madame Tussaud's museum tickets. There I found three types tickets for this museum.

1. MADAME TUSSAUD'S DC + BIG BUS
2. EXTREME VALUE TICKET
3. ONLINE SAVER

Under the second category they mention that Admission + Wax Hand. Immortalize your hand in wax! It is a one-of-a-kind memento of your visit!

Do they give us a souvenir of our own hands created from wax at the same time? Or what do they mean by this?

Does anyone have prior experience?

Comment: If you search [Tussauds wax hand](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Tussauds+wax+hand) on YouTube, you can see plenty of videos of exactly what they do.

Answer (score 1):

The Wax Hand at Tussaud's museum is actually a process where you hand will be gradually covered with wax, which wax will then be removed from your hand so that you can take it as a souvenir.

I have no prior experience but that is strongly suggested by various pictures and videos that you can find using 'tussaud hand wax' in your preferred search engine.

[image: some hand wax being done]

Some people seem to be disappointed because their wax hand broke quickly.

Comment: I was going to say...I've never seen what they do there specifically (nor would I, personally, rank Madame Tussauds high on the list of the many things to see in DC, but to each their own), but wax hands are usually pretty fragile. I wouldn't want to try to get one home in one piece from vacation, especially if I was flying.